# Calculating the size of a full outer join in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, combinatorics

### tl;dr

My issue here is that I'm stuck at calculating how many rows to anticipate on each part of a full outer merge when using Pandas DataFrames as part of a combinatorics graph.

### Questions (repeated below).

1. The ideal solution would be to not require the merge and to query [`panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html) objects. Given that there isn't a query method on the `panel` is there a cleaner solution which would solve this problem without hitting the memory ceiling?
2. If the answer to 2 is no, how can I calculate the size of the required merge table for each combination of sets *without carrying out the merge*? This might be a sub-optimal approach but in this instance it would be acceptable for the purpose of the application.
3. Is Python the right language for this or should I be looking at a more statistical language such as `R` or write it at a lower level (`c`, `cython`) - *Databases are out of the question.*

### The problem

Recently I re-wrote the [py-upset graphing library](https://github.com/mproffitt/py-upset/tree/feature/ISSUE-7-Severe-Performance-Degradation/src/pyupset) to make it more efficient in terms of time when calculating combinations across DataFrames. I'm not looking for a review of this code, it works perfectly well in most instances and I'm happy with the approach. What I am looking for now is the answer to a very specific problem; uncovered when working with large data-sets.

The approach I took with the re-write was to formulate an in-memory merge of all provided dataframes on a full outer join as seen on lines [480 - 502 of `pyupset.resources`](https://github.com/mproffitt/py-upset/blob/feature/ISSUE-7-Severe-Performance-Degradation/src/pyupset/resources.py#L480)

```
        for index, key in enumerate(keys):
            frame = self._frames[key]
            frame.columns = [
                '{0}_{1}'.format(column, key)
                if column not in self._unique_keys
                else
                column
                for column in self._frames[key].columns
            ]
            if index == 0:
                self._merge = frame
            else:
                suffixes = (
                    '_{0}'.format(keys[index-1]),
                    '_{0}'.format(keys[index]),
                )
                self._merge = self._merge.merge(
                    frame,
                    on=self._unique_keys,
                    how='outer',
                    copy=False,
                    suffixes=suffixes
                )
```

For small to medium dataframes using joins works incredibly well. In fact recent performance tests have shown that it'll handle 5 or 6 Data-Sets containing 10,000's of lines each in a less than a minute which is more than ample for the application structure I require.

The problem now moves from time based to memory based.

Given datasets of potentially 100s of thousands of records, the library very quickly runs out of memory even on a large server.

To put this in perspective, my test machine for this application is an 8-core VMWare box with 128GiB RAM running Centos7.

Given the following dataset sizes, when adding the 5th dataframe, memory usage spirals exponentially. This was pretty much anticipated but underlines the heart of the problem I am facing.

```
  Rows | Dataframe
------------------------
 13963 | dataframe_one
 48346 | dataframe_two
 52356 | dataframe_three
337292 | dataframe_four
 49936 | dataframe_five
 24542 | dataframe_six
258093 | dataframe_seven
 16337 | dataframe_eight
```

These are not "*small*" dataframes in terms of the number of rows although the column count for each is limited to one unique key + 4 non-unique columns. The size of each column in `pandas` is

```
column | type     | unique
--------------------------
X      | object   | Y
id     | int64    | N
A      | float64  | N
B      | float64  | N
C      | float64  | N
```

This merge can cause problems as memory is eaten up. Occasionally it aborts with a MemoryError (great, I can catch and handle those), other times the kernel takes over and simply kills the application before the system becomes unstable, and occasionally, the system just hangs and becomes unresponsive / unstable until finally the kernel kills the application and frees the memory.

*Sample output (memory sizes approximate):*

```
[INFO] Creating merge table
[INFO] Merging table dataframe_one
[INFO] Data index length = 13963     # approx memory <500MiB
[INFO] Merging table dataframe_two
[INFO] Data index length = 98165     # approx memory <1.8GiB
[INFO] Merging table dataframe_three
[INFO] Data index length = 1296665   # approx memory <3.0GiB
[INFO] Merging table dataframe_four
[INFO] Data index length = 244776542 # approx memory ~13GiB
[INFO] Merging table dataframe_five
Killed # > 128GiB
```

When the merge table has been produced, it is queried in set combinations to produce graphs similar to https://github.com/mproffitt/py-upset/blob/feature/ISSUE-7-Severe-Performance-Degradation/tests/generated/extra_additional_pickle.png

The approach I am trying to build for solving the memory issue is to look at the sets being offered for merge, pre-determine how much memory the merge will require, then if that combination requires too much, split it into smaller combinations, calculate each of those separately, then put the final dataframe back together (divide and conquer).

My issue here is that I'm stuck at calculating how many rows to anticipate on each part of the merge.

### Questions (repeated from above)

1. The ideal solution would be to not require the merge and to query [`panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html) objects. Given that there isn't a query method on the `panel` is there a cleaner solution which would solve this problem without hitting the memory ceiling?
2. If the answer to 2 is no, how can I calculate the size of the required merge table for each combination of sets *without carrying out the merge*? This might be a sub-optimal approach but in this instance it would be acceptable for the purpose of the application.
3. Is Python the right language for this or should I be looking at a more statistical language such as `R` or write it at a lower level (`c`, `cython`).

Apologies for the lengthy question. I'm happy to provide more information if required or possible.

Can anybody shed some light on what might be the reason for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1.

[Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) shows a lot of promise in being able to calculate the merge table "out of memory" by using hdf5 files as a temporary store.

By using multi-processing to create the merges, dask also offers a performance increase over `pandas`. Unfortunately this is not carried through to the `query` method so performance gains made on the merge are lost on querying.

It is still not a completely viable solution as dask may still run out of memory on large, complex merges.

## Question 2.

Pre-calculating the size of the merge is entirely possible using the following method.

1. Group each dataframe by a unique key and calculate the size.
2. Create a set of key names for each dataframe.
3. Create an intersection of sets from 2.
4. Create a set difference for set 1 and for set 2
5. To accommodate for `np.nan` stored in the unique key, select all NAN values. If one frame contains nan and the other doesn't, write the other as 1.
6. for sets in the intersection, multiply the count from each `groupby('...').size()`
7. Add counts from the set differences
8. Add a count of `np.nan` values

In python this could be written as:

```
def merge_size(left_frame, right_frame, group_by):
    left_groups = left_frame.groupby(group_by).size()
    right_groups = right_frame.groupby(group_by).size()
    left_keys = set(left_groups.index)
    right_keys = set(right_groups.index)
    intersection = right_keys & left_keys
    left_sub_right = left_keys - intersection
    right_sub_left = right_keys - intersection

    left_nan = len(left_frame.query('{0} != {0}'.format(group_by)))
    right_nan = len(right_frame.query('{0} != {0}'.format(group_by)))
    left_nan = 1 if left_nan == 0 and right_nan != 0 else left_nan
    right_nan = 1 if right_nan == 0 and left_nan != 0 else right_nan

    sizes = [(left_groups[group_name] * right_groups[group_name]) for group_name in intersection]
    sizes += [left_groups[group_name] for group_name in left_sub_right]
    sizes += [right_groups[group_name] for group_name in right_sub_left]
    sizes += [left_nan * right_nan]
    return sum(sizes)
```

## Question 3

This method is fairly heavy on calculating and would be better written in `Cython` for performance gains.